# How to fix the issue-No action was found on the controller that matches the name on sending JSON object to ASP.NET WebAPI from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass data entered in AngularJS front end to webAPI and retrieve another set of data to populate on a grid. I am trying to pass data as JSON object to webAPI method. In WebAPI method, the parameter I am passing for the JSON object as a Class object.

I am not able to enter to the particular webAPI method when I am using [HTTPPost] and getting error as-**No action was found on the controller that matches the request.**

But I am able to enter to other webAPI methods having [HTTPGet].

Can someone please advise how to fix the issue.Thanks !

**WebAPI**

```
using System.Web.Http;
using AttributeRouting.Web.Http;

namespace webAPITestProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Values")] 
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        retrieveEmployeeData empData = new retrieveEmployeeData();
        retrieveProductDetails prodDetls = new retrieveProductDetails();    

        [Route("PostEmployeeData")] 
        [HttpPost]
        public DataTable PostEmployeeData([FromBody] Employer empDetails)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable { TableName = "MyTableName" };
            dataTable = empData.getEmployeeData(empDetails);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

**AngularJS-Controller**

```
angular.module('Test.Employer')
    .controller('EmployerController', ['$scope','headerValue', '$http',
        function ($scope, headerValue, $http) { 
            var ipEmployerDetls = {                   
                EmployerName: "cherokee",
                Company: "ABC"                   
            };

            $http({ 
                url: 'http://localhost:53583/api/Values/PostEmployeeData?empDetails='+'"'+JSON.stringify(ipEmployerDetls)+'"',
                dataType: 'json', 
                method: 'POST', 
                data: JSON.stringify(ipEmployerDetls), 
                headers: { 
                    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
                } 
            }).success(function (response) { 
                $scope.object = response.data;
            }) 
                .error(function (error) { 
                    alert(error.Message); 
                });
})();
```

**Employer class**

```
public class Employer
{
    public string Company{get;set;}
    public string EmployerName{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are POSTing data to an endpoint, you don't need to add anything in the URL.

```
  $http({ 
                url: 'http://localhost:53583/api/Values/PostEmployeeData',
                dataType: 'json', 
                method: 'POST', 
                data: JSON.stringify(ipEmployerDetls), 
                headers: { 
                    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
                } 
            }).success(function (response) { 
                $scope.object = response.data;
            }) 
                .error(function (error) { 
                    alert(error.Message); 
                });
```

I have cleaned up your call, the data you provide is sent in the body of the message and your controller expects it there as indicated by the *[FromBody]* tag

Comment: Thanks for your advise.I alreday tried this.But it still showing the same error.

Comment: Also I am getting the below error-Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:53583/api/Values/PostEmployeeData' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.Can someone please advise.